# How to read compressed data in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, base64, compression

A database has a column which contains XML data and a CDATA section that holds a Base64 encoded zip file. Using XmlReader, I was able to get a string from the CDATA section but after decoding & decompressing the string with the code, I am getting null from the decompressed data. Help please

```
case XmlNodeType.CDATA:

   string base64EncodedData = xreader.Value;
   var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);//convert to bytes

   string decoded = Unzip(base64EncodedBytes);

   writer.WriteString("decoded:"+decoded);
   break;
```

---

```
public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                try { gs.CopyTo(mso); }
                catch { Console.Write("failed"); }
                //CopyTo(gs, mso);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of the column where you store the xml? is it XML column? What is the encoding you used in XML? if not specified anything the XML will default to UTF8. But SQL XML column accepts UTF-16.

Comment: Also tried other ways to decompress data but got "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream." or some unreadable text.